# pydrive library for google drive is not downloading file in requested format using requests

Tags: python, csv, python-requests, pydrive

I have a simple script set up for getting a file off my google drive account and updating it. I have no problems authenticating and getting access to the drive. The file is in the form of a google spreadsheet on the drive. Thus, when I have the pydrive file object, I get the URL of the file in csv format via `google_file['exportLinks']['text/csv']`. This has worked in the past, however today I tried this same method for a new file, and instead of getting the csv format of the data, I keep getting HTML. In addition, if I copy and paste the link from my `google_file['exportLink']['text/csv']` and put it into a browser, the browser will begin to download the file in csv format as requested. I really have no idea what is going on, especially since this has worked in the past.

Here is basically what my code does:

```
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

drivefiles  = drive.ListFile().GetList()
form_file = None

for f in drivefiles:
    if f['title'] == formFileName:
        form_file = f
        break

output = requests.get(form_file['exportLinks']['text/csv'])
print output.text #this ends up being HTML, not text/csv
```

Has anyone else out there seen this problem before? Should I just try to delete and re-add the google spreadsheet file on the drive?

EDIT: UPDATE

So, after changing permissions on the file on google drive from accessible only to people who the file has been shared with to accessible/editable by all, I was able to access and download the file. Does the clients_secret.json file allow a particular google drive user to securely authorize or is that a general key that allows anyone with it to access the Google API in that particular session? Are there any special data that has to be send over the http request if the file has only been shared with a limited set of email addresses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else has been having problems with this, changing the settings on the file in the drive to "everyone can view" solved the problem - seems that there were some permission restrictions. Would suggest that you look into changing the permissions on the file to the least restrictive setting (as possible) while debugging.

Answer (score 0):

I also found handling idiosyncrasies of google drive api little bit tricky. I have written a wrapper around google drive api, which makes it relatively easy to deal with it. See if it helps:-

[Google Drive Client](https://gist.github.com/hspandher/726e72a657ac23c9293b)

Sample code:-

```
file_id = 'abc'
file_access_token = '34244324324'

scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'
path_to_private_key_file = '#'
service_account_name = '284765467291-0qnqb1do03dlaj0crl88srh4pbhocj35@developer.gserviceaccount.com'

drive_client = GoogleDriveClient(
               scope = scope,
               private_key = open(path_to_private_key_file).read(),
               service_account_name = service_account_name)

file = drive_client.get_drive_file(file_id, file_access_token)
```

Ofcourse, you need to change access variables according to your profile.

Comment: That's fine, but how or why is this different from what I've already done?